# How can I make make my Jenkins server on AWS reachable by my Github webhook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration

My goal is to just have a setup where Github sends a hook to my Jenkins server to trigger it to do something.

I made a free AWS Windows container and installed Jenkins on it.

Now, since Jenkins runs on localhost:8080, I figure Tomcat or some server has been installed. So it would make sense to me that I could do something like:

```
public-dns.aws.com:8080
```

And be able to access Jenkins. This works in the container but it says that it takes too long to connect to the server when done on a different machine.

What am I doing wrong? I apologize for the noob question.

Comment: Are you using ECS or EC2?

Comment: @CélineAussourd, I'm using EC2.

Comment: Then you need to open port 8080 to your IP and to Github's IPs in the instance Security Group.

Comment: That did it, thanks! :D

Comment: Did it work for you? How did you do it?